# when console log of array object that been reverse and join that return a letter

Tags: javascript, arrays, string, object

I have an array with 2 object and when reverse and join this array and consoled log with first or second index , that return letter like 'j', 'b'

```js
list = [{
    name: 'anne',
    age: 20,
    gender: 'F'
  },
  {
    name: 'david',
    age: 50,
    gender: 'M'
  },
  {
    name: 'mark',
    age: 33,
    gender: 'M'
  },
]

var val = this.list.slice().reverse().join('');

console.log('val ==> ', val[2]) // val ==>  b
```

what is this b ?

Comment: Have you tried `console.log(val)`?

Comment: Try `console.log(val)`.

Comment: @georg hi , yes it returned  val ==>  [object Object][object Object][object Object]

Comment: `b` is simply the third character of that string.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Because you're using `join("")`, that calls the `toString` method on every item in the array - they happen to be objects, and the `toString` method of an object returns `[object Object]`:

```js
let obj = {};
console.log(obj.toString());
```

You can avoid this issue by mapping with `JSON.stringify` first.

```js
var list = [{name:'anne',age:20,gender:'F'},{name:'david',age:50,gender:'M'},{name:'mark',age:33,gender:'M'}];
const res = this.list.slice().reverse().map(JSON.stringify).join('');
console.log("res[2] ===> ", res[2]); //Returns "n" because {"n are the first three characters in the string
console.log(res);
```

```css
.as-console-wrapper { max-height: 100% !important; top: auto; }
```

Note that the above still returns a character. If you want to get an object, remove the `join` and `map`:

```js
var list = [{name:'anne',age:20,gender:'F'},{name:'david',age:50,gender:'M'},{name:'mark',age:33,gender:'M'}];
const res = this.list.slice().reverse();
console.log("res[2] ===> ", res[2]); //Returns "n" because {"n are the first three characters in the string
console.log(res);
```

```css
.as-console-wrapper { max-height: 100% !important; top: auto; }
```